# How to retain color when piping `git difftool` to pager

Tags: git, colors, pager, less-unix

I cannot get:

```
git difftool -b -y -x "diff --color --suppress-common-lines -y -w -W 200" master:file.txt file.txt
```

to retain its coloured output when piping to `less -R`. What am I doing wrong?

I think I've tried all the git color config options, e.g.

```
git -c color.ui=always difftool --color=always -b -y -x "diff --color --suppress-common-lines -y -w -W 200" master:file.txt file.txt | less -R
```

But there's no color. As soon as I remove the pipe to `less -R`, I see coloured output. Any ideas?

**Edit:** Thanks to @jonathan-wakely, I was missing the `=always` argument to the `--color` option in the external `difftool` `diff` command. This now keeps the colors when piping to less:

```
git difftool -b -y -x "/usr/local/bin/diff --color=always --suppress-common-lines -y -w -W 200" master:file.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean `difftool`, not just `diff`? Because `difftool` calls a *diff tool* (like `vimdiff`) for every file, not pipes diff to std output. What `difftool` have you configured?

Comment: `git diff --color=always | less -R` works for me, shows colors perfectly.

Comment: @phd I'm using `diff` with side-by-side  (`-y -W 200`) options as the external difftool

Comment: Then you need `--color=always` in the "tool". `git difftool -x 'diff --color=always -y -W 50' | less -R` works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colours are not coming from `git` they're coming from the external diff tool, so that's what decides whether to use colours or not. So you need to use `-x "diff --color=always ..."` to tell `diff` to use colours even when the output is not going to the terminal.

Comment: I just can't get this to work. `git difftool -y -x 'diff --color=always'` results in a bunch of `diff: unrecognized option '--color=always'`